# Why does physics need high-dimensional spheres?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, string-theory, phase-space

Under what physical scenarios do the properties of high-dimensional spheres come in handy? If physics is 3 or 4-dimensional, when does one need to interest oneself in spheres of dimensionality higher than 4 and how is this useful? Does it happen when the underlying reality involves higher dimensions as in string theory, or in phase or parameter spaces that may have very high dimensions?

Comment: It's interesting that you tagged this statistical mechanics. Or did someone else do it? That's an obvious field were spaces of large dimension (>4) occur.

Comment: i was in a middle of writing a very nice answer (I think) when this question was closed? why? I think it is clear enough

Comment: To get the question reopened, you might want to mention a few sources, e.g. The Scientific American article ["Why You Should Care about High-Dimensional Sphere Packing"](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/why-you-should-care-about-high-dimensional-sphere-packing/). Or that higher-dimensional spheres are sometimes mentioned in [string theory papers](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?start=10&q=%22higher+dimensional+spheres%22+%22string+theory%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

Comment: @yyy I think the expression "come in handy" is pretty vague.  What one person might consider as "coming in handy" would be what another might describe as "over-complex".  I'm not sure there's a neat answer to this to match the SE format of Q&A.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why are extra dimensions necessary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10527/2451)

Comment: I agree the extra dimensions question is relevant, but  [7 sphere, is there any physical interpretation of exotic spheres?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43683) may be a better specific example of what the OP is looking for, as would the 5-spheres that I believe figure in $AdS_5 \times S^5$  theory.  
Beyond string theory, I think wikipedia is correct when it says "All classical statistical physics is based on the [concentration of measure](https://tinyurl.com/2p88nnky)", which follows from the "all mass is near the equator" property of very high dimensional spheres.

Comment: The context of OP's post (v3) seems unclear. E.g. string theory is only causally mentioned in the last sentence.